# validating post method data in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple model:

```
     class News(models.Model):
         viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
         headline = models.CharField()
```

Given headline, I want to set the viewed to True. My question revolves around structuring the app/code base. Where do I validate the headline exists and update it?

serializer.py

```
     class NewsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
         def validate(self,data):
           try:
              news = News.objects.get(headline=data.get('headline'))
              return data
           except:
              raise serializer.ValidationError('headlinenotfound')
```

views.py

```
    def post(self, request):
         headline = request.data.headline
         serializer = NewsSerializer(data=request.data)
         if serializer.is_valid():
              #get the news to update
              news = News.object.get(headline=headline)
              news.viewed = True
              news.save()
```

Comment: What do you mean `validate headline`?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are looking for a given headline and if there is a News object with this headline then you want to set viewed=True for all the subsequent News objects. Is my assumption correct? If so then the try catch block is wrong. two possible exceptions: 'Object not found' and 'multiple objects returned' for a get query (since headline is not unique). You are just assuming 'Object Not' found here And we need more input for your question.